# Investment Feedback

Tags: investing, fidelity

I am new to investing and have been trying to create a cadence of continuous mutual fund investment. I have made my first week of purchases using the scheme below. I am seeking feedback on this strategy. Is it sufficiently diversified? Is it wise to continue purchasing on this scheme for all of 2020? Should I have ETFs in the mix? Is this an aggressive breakout? Thanks!

Breakout

30% Domestic Equity (FSKAX, or the ZERO version, FZROX)

15% International Equity (FSPSX)

10% Emerging Markets (FPADX)

15% Inflation-Protected Treasuries (FIPDX)

15% U.S. Treasuries (FUAMX)

15% Real Estate

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty good, and depending upon your age and risk tolerance, this could work for the rest of your life.  I do not think you need to add ETFs, mutual funds are fine for your purchases.

However here is my **opinion** which can be discarded if your risk tolerance will not let you sleep safe at night.  This would apply if you are under the age of 60.

For US equity, I would be about 20% in FSKAX, 25% S&P500, and 25% in NASDAQ.  Yes you could lose half this value, effectively overnight, but as you are just starting out that will not amount to much, and if history proves itself over, It will recover.

Forget treasuries, maybe 10% total bonds.

I'd do 5% in international equity and 5% in emerging markets if you wish.  You get a lot of international exposure from the other equity funds.

10-15% real estate is okay.

All in all, pretty good choices.